# Compare elements of array based on position of elements

Tags: javascript

i need to compare array first position with the one in the last position, the second with the second to last one, and so on. using javascript

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

1 with 6, 2 with 5 and 3 with 4

the real deal i need to compare properties of objects if it is equals i need to compare another property (note and year)

```
 function compare(arr) {
        const n = arr.length
        const mid = Math.floor(n / 2)
        const second = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
           if (arr[i].note === arr[n - i - 1].note) {
                if (arr[i].year > arr[n - i - 1].year) {
                    second.push(arr[i])
                } else {
                    second.push(arr[n - i - 1])
                }
            } else if (arr[i].note > arr[n - i - 1].note) {
                second.push(arr[i])
            } else {
                second.push(arr[n - i - 1])
            }
        }
        return second
    }
```

Comment: What stops you?

Comment: i need to compare properties of objects inside the array, and im think im using to much loops for that

Comment: I can't see any loop. Where are they? Show your code.

Comment: Does the array always have the same number of items? The last sentence in the question suggests (and also the rest of the question) suggests that it always has 6 items.

Comment: always had 8 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate half of the array and compare the element with the opposite one

```js
function compare(arr) {
  const n = arr.length
  const mid = Math.floor(n / 2)

  for (let i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
    console.log("comparing", arr[i], "and", arr[n - i - 1])
    // do your comparision
  }
}

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
compare(arr)

console.log('---')

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
compare(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`i = ${i}, element: ${arr[i]}, mirrored: ${arr[arr.length - i - 1]}`);
}
```

I think this is what you need

Output:

```
i = 0, element: 1, mirrored: 6
i = 1, element: 2, mirrored: 5
i = 2, element: 3, mirrored: 4
i = 3, element: 4, mirrored: 3
i = 4, element: 5, mirrored: 2
i = 5, element: 6, mirrored: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability I would create a function that compares two items and returns the winner:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.note === b.note) {
    if (a.year > b.year) {
      return a;
    } else {
      return b;
    }
  } else {
    if (a.note > b.note) {
      return a;
    } else {
      return b;
    }
  }
}
```

It can be written more compact, but not necessarily easier to read, like this:

```js
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.note === b.note) {
    // If the marks are equal then check the years; the greater year wins
    return (a.year > b.year) ? a : b;
  } else {
    // Otherwise the greater mark wins
    return (a.note > b.note) ? a : b;
  }
}
```

Since the input array has a fixed, known size, the rest of the code can be written to clearly express what items are compared:

```js
const second = [];
second.push(compare(arr[0], arr[7]));
second.push(compare(arr[1], arr[6]));
second.push(compare(arr[2], arr[5]));
second.push(compare(arr[3], arr[4]));
```

---

If the size of the input array is not fixed then a loop is required. Use a variable to store the index of the first item and another one for an index of the last item. Compare the items then advance each index towards each other until they meet:

```js
const second = [];
for (head = 0, tail = arr.length - 1; head < tail; head ++, tail --) {
  second.push(compare(arr[head], arr[tail]));
}
```